# Problem with downloading and displaying image

Tags: java, swing

I have made a program in Java, that downloads an image from the internet, given a link, and saves it into a specific folder in my computer, upon the pressing of a button in the gui. What I want to do next is to display that image on the screen. Please note, the URL input is not necessarily the URL of the image itself, but of an HTML webpage containing the image. The problem is, I can't simply create an ImageIcon object preemptively, because the image file doesn't exist in the system yet in compile time.

**Panel Class**

```
public class AdditionPanel extends JPanel
{

    // ...
    static JTextPane textpane;
    JLabel paneInstructions;
    JButton linkOk;

    public AdditionPanel() throws IOException
    {

        textpane = new JTextPane();         
        paneInstructions = new JLabel("Paste the link here:");
        linkOk = new JButton(" OK ");

        // ...

        linkOk.addActionListener(new LinkOkPressed());

        // ...

        this.add(textpane);
        this.add(paneInstructions);
        this.add(linkOk);
    }
}
```

An idea I've had is to create an ActionListener for that button, and try to access the file only after the button has been pressed, and thus the file has been downloaded. In this case, I don't know how to make an image display on a JPanel, from a different class.

**Action Listener**

```
public class LinkOkPressed implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel test;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // ImageDownloader is a class I have created, that simply saves the image
        // from the given URL in a predetermined directory
        ImageDownloader.saveImage(ImageDownloader.getImageUrl(AdditionPanel.textpane.getText()));
        ImageIcon poster = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/myimage.png"));
        test= new JLabel(poster);
        AdditionPanel.add(test); // Does not work
    }

}
```

So, can I add an image to the panel from a different class, or is there a better way to access a file that is downloaded during the runtime of the app? Thanks for the help.

**ImageDownloader**

```
public class ImageDownloader
{
    public static String getImageUrl(String imdbLink)
    {
        String imageLink = "";
        try
        {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(imdbLink).get();
            Elements divs = doc.getElementsByClass("poster");
            Element poster = divs.first();
            Elements image = poster.getElementsByTag("a");
            Element downloadImage = image.first();
            Elements img = downloadImage.getElementsByTag("img");
            imageLink = img.attr("src");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageLink;
    }


    public static void saveImage(String imageLink)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try
        {
            URL url =new URL(imageLink);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\...\\resources\\myimage.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ImageIcon poster = new ImageIcon(new URL(AdditionPanel.textpane.getText()));` work?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. The URL inputted is not the URL of the image itself. Specifically, I've made the program so that I input the URL of an IMDb page, and the ImageDownloader class uses JSoup to extract the URL of the image of the movie's poster. I will clarify in my question.

Comment: You need to obtain the **instance** of your `AdditionPanel` inside your Action Listener. Hint: `e` -> its source -> parent

Comment: @PM77-1 I appreciate the reply. I understand what you're suggesting, but I don't know how to do it in Java. Could please elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on *PM 77-1*'s comment.

```
public class LinkOkPressed implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel test;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // ImageDownloader is a class I have created, that simply saves the image
        // from the given URL in a predetermined directory
        ImageDownloader.saveImage(ImageDownloader.getImageUrl(AdditionPanel.textpane.getText()));
        ImageIcon poster = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/myimage.png"));
        test= new JLabel(poster);
        Object obj = e.getSource(); // "obj" is really "linkOk" from class "AdditionPanel"
        java.awt.Container parent = ((JButton) obj).getParent(); // "parent" is instance of "AdditionPanel"
        ((JPanel) parent).add(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your solution works perfectly for images that already exist in that folder, but unfortunately, still throws NullPointerException for the newly downloaded image, even though theoretically, the image is already there when poster is assigned a value. Also, I had to add "javax.swing." to your type casts.

Comment: I'm guessing that the saving of the image takes time and is done in a separate thread. Hence the `JLabel` is created **before** the image has been saved.

Comment: Understood. Any ideas on how to account for that in the program? I will probably create a new question for that. You have already helped me quite a lot here. Thanks!

Comment: I would use `SwingWorker`. See lesson [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) in Oracle Java Tutorial. Launch the task in your `actionPerformed()` method. When the task completes it notifies `PropertyListener`s. If you want me to post sample code then first post a complete example so I can copy it and run it and then change it as required.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on my own, and, as I'm not familiar with SwingWorker, failed. Unfortunately, the complete program is way too large. I have updated the question with my failed attempt at using SwingWorker. If that doesn't help, don't worry, I'll figure it out. Regardlessly, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`SwingWorker` example.

Create a separate class like so...

```
public class SaveImage extends javax.swing.SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private AdditionPanel additionPanel;

    public SaveImage(AdditionPanel addPanel) {
        additionPanel = addPanel;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        ImageDownloader.saveImage(ImageDownloader.getImageUrl(AdditionPanel.textpane.getText()));
        // Wait until the image is saved.
        // Since I don't have code for class "ImageDownloader", can't tell you how to do this.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        javax.swing.ImageIcon poster = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/myimage.png"));
        javax.swing.JLabel test= new javax.swing.JLabel(poster);
        additionPanel.add(test);
    }
}
```

And change your `LinkOkPressed` class like so...

```
public class LinkOkPressed implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object obj = e.getSource(); // "obj" is really "linkOk" from class "AdditionPanel"
        java.awt.Container parent = ((JButton) obj).getParent(); // "parent" is instance of "AdditionPanel"
        SaveImage saveImage = new SaveImage((AdditionPanel) parent);
        saveImage.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: If only I could accept both answers! I followed the example, but I'm still getting NullPointerException, on the line `ImageIcon poster = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/myimage.png"));`

Comment: Replace `getClass()` in that line with `LinkOkPressed.class`

Comment: Thanks for the patience. Unfortunately, that was not the reason for the error. I don't get it: shouldn't the contents of done() be executed after whatever is in doInBackground() is completed? At least, that is what I understood from reading about SwingWorker.